# vba macro not able to download file thru FTP

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click() 
    Dim myURL As String
    myURL = "ftp://11.11.11.11/sample/myfile.txt"

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile "D:\FTPFOLDER\file.txt", 2 
        oStream.Close
        MsgBox "success"
    Else
        MsgBox "not success"
        MsgBox WinHttpReq.Status
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried above VBA macro code, it didn't download the file from the FTP URL.
But it didn't show any errors. Anything I need to install any plugin/any access I need to provide.  Whether I add/include any references .Anyone have any idea

**Note : Thru Filezilla I can able to upload and download my files**

Comment: What is the result of `WinHttpReq.Status`? If status if different from 200 your code does nothing and just shows `MsgBox "success"` which is not true. Success should be only if `WinHttpReq.Status = 200` else no success.

Comment: WinHttpReq.Status is 0

Comment: An HTTP request is not an FTP request. WinHTTP doesn't do FTP, it only does HTTP(S).

Comment: You could execute Filezilla through VBA.  Or Run FTP through a command prompt using a FileScriptingObject instead